# how can I count number of lines after a string match until next especific match occurs

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a file with the following structure (see below), I need help to find the way to match every ">Cluster" string, and for every case count the number of lines until the next ">cluster" and so on until the end of the file.

```
>Cluster 0
0       10565nt, >CL9602.Contig1_All... *
1       1331nt, >CL9602.Contig2_All... at -/98.05%
>Cluster 1
0       3798nt, >CL3196.Contig1_All... at +/97.63%
1       9084nt, >CL3196.Contig3_All... *
>Cluster 2
0       8710nt, >Unigene21841_All... *
>Cluster 3
0       8457nt, >Unigene10299_All... *
```

The desired Output should look like below:

```
Cluster 0  2 
Cluster 1  2
Cluster 2  1
Cluster 3  1
```

I tried with awk as below, but it gives me only the line numbers.

```
awk '{print FNR "\t" $0}' All-Unigene_Clustered.fa.clstr | head - 20
==> standard input <==
1       >Cluster 0
2       0       10565nt, >CL9602.Contig1_All... *
3       1       1331nt, >CL9602.Contig2_All... at -/98.05%
4       >Cluster 1
5       0       3798nt, >CL3196.Contig1_All... at +/97.63%
6       1       9084nt, >CL3196.Contig3_All... *
7       >Cluster 2
8       0       8710nt, >Unigene21841_All... *
9       >Cluster 3
10      0       8457nt, >Unigene10299_All... *
```

I also tried with sed, but it only prints the lines while even ommiting some lines.

```
sed -n -e '/>Cluster/,/>Cluster/ p' All-Unigene_Clustered.fa.clstr | head             
>Cluster 0
0       10565nt, >CL9602.Contig1_All... *
1       1331nt, >CL9602.Contig2_All... at -/98.05%
>Cluster 1
>Cluster 2
0       8710nt, >Unigene21841_All... *
>Cluster 3
>Cluster 4
0       1518nt, >CL2313.Contig1_All... at -/95.13%
1       8323nt, >CL2313.Contig8_All... *
```

In addition I tried awk and sed in combination with 'wc' but it gives me only the total count of occurrencies for the string match.

I thought subtracting the lines not matching the string '>cluster' using the -v option of grep, then substracting every line matching the string '>Cluster' and adding both to a new file, e.g

```
grep -vw '>Cluster' All-Unigene_Clustered.fa.clstr | head
0       10565nt, >CL9602.Contig1_All... *
1       1331nt, >CL9602.Contig2_All... at -/98.05%
0       3798nt, >CL3196.Contig1_All... at +/97.63%
1       9084nt, >CL3196.Contig3_All... *
0       8710nt, >Unigene21841_All... *
0       8457nt, >Unigene10299_All... *
0       1518nt, >CL2313.Contig1_All... at -/95.13%

grep -w '>Cluster' All-Unigene_Clustered.fa.clstr | head
>Cluster 0
>Cluster 1
>Cluster 2
>Cluster 3
>Cluster 4
```

but the problem is that the number of lines following each '>Cluster' isn't constant, each '>Cluster' string is followed by 1, 2, 3 or more lines until the next string occurs.

I have decided to post my question after extensively searching for help within previously ansewred questions but I could't find any helpful answer.

Thanks

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.(I don't downvote btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^>Cluster/{
  if(count){
    print prev,count
  }
  sub(/^>/,"")
  prev=$0
  count=""
  next
}
{
  count++
}
END{
  if(count && prev){
    print prev,count
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>Cluster/{               ##Checking condition if a line is having string Cluster then do following.
  if(count){               ##Checking condition if variable count is NOT NULL then do following.
    print prev,count       ##Printing prev and count variable here.
  }                        ##Closing BLOCK for if condition here.
  sub(/^>/,"")             ##Using sub for substitution of starting > with NULL in current line.
  prev=$0                  ##Creating a variable named prev whose value is current line.
  count=""                 ##Nullifying count variable here.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                          ##Closing BLOCK for Cluster condition here.
{
  count++                  ##Doing increment of variable count each time cursor comes here.
}
END{                       ##Mentioning END BLOCK for this program.
  if(count && prev){       ##Checking condition if variable count and prev are NOT NULL then do following.
    print prev,count       ##Printing prev and count variable here.
  }                        ##Closing BLOCK for if condition here.
}                          ##Closing BLOCK for END BLOCK of this program.
' Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Cluster 0 2
Cluster 1 2
Cluster 2 1
Cluster 3 1
```

Comment: THANK you very much RavinderSingh13. This solution works perfectly. In order for me and perhaps others to understand and learn a bit more, could you please if it isn't a problem explain a how this code works.

Comment: @LeonardoMartin, Detailed explanation is already added in my post, kindly go through it and lemme know if any queries here?

Comment: This works except for lines that have 0 count (then it simply ignores showing that line). Would be great if it showed 'Cluster 1 0' (if 'Cluster 1' had no lines underneath it)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)(>|$)' -F'\n' 'NR>1{print $1, NF-1}' file
Cluster 0 2
Cluster 1 2
Cluster 2 1
Cluster 3 1
```

The above just separates the input into records that start with `>` at the start of a line and then prints the number of lines in each record (subtracting 1 for the `>Cluster...` line).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a, allbeit quite verbose one liner in `Perl`. I'm really not good at this golfing stuff.

```
perl -n -e "if ( /^>(.+)/ ) { print qq($last, $count\n) if $count; $last = $1; $count = 0; } else { $count++ } END { print qq($last, $count) }" All-Unigene_Clustered.fa.clstr
```

This is for Windows. For a unix shell you probably need to change the double to single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help with my question, your suggested Code unfortunately don't produce the desired Output, see below

Comment: It produces the output you wanted, given your example data. Well, except for the comma, but it is trivial to remove that.

Comment: it was something like this                                                                                                      0>Cluster 31021, 1>Cluster 31021, 1>Cluster 31022, 0>Cluster 31022, 1>Cluster 31022, 1>Cluster 31023, 0>Cluster 31023, 1>Cluster 31023,

Comment: Right, the `,` and the `>`. I removed them. Pls try again

Answer (score 1):

In perl the code can be in following form

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cluster;
my $count;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    if( /Cluster \d+/ ) {
        print "$cluster $count\n" if defined $cluster;
        s/>//;
        $cluster = $_;
        $count   = 0;
    } else {
        $count++;
    }
}

print "$cluster $count\n" if defined $store;

__DATA__
>Cluster 0
0       10565nt, >CL9602.Contig1_All... *
1       1331nt, >CL9602.Contig2_All... at -/98.05%
>Cluster 1
0       3798nt, >CL3196.Contig1_All... at +/97.63%
1       9084nt, >CL3196.Contig3_All... *
>Cluster 2
0       8710nt, >Unigene21841_All... *
>Cluster 3
0       8457nt, >Unigene10299_All... *
```

output

```
Cluster 0 2
Cluster 1 2
Cluster 2 1
Cluster 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following awk also works for 0 count lines (ie no lines until the next match):

```
BEGIN {
    count = 0;
    prev = "";
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /LOGCL/) {
        if (prev) {
            print (prev ": " count);
        }

        #reset count & assign line to prev
        count = 0;
        prev = $0;

    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
END {
    print (prev ": " count);
}
```

So for following file (put above into count.awk and invoke with
`awk -f count.awk test.txt`):

test.txt:

```
LOGCL One
Blah
LOGCL Two
Blah
Blah
LOGCL Three
LOGCL Four
Blah
LOGCL Five
blah
blah
blah
```

Output is:

```
LOGCL One: 1
LOGCL Two: 2
LOGCL Three: 0
LOGCL Four: 1
LOGCL Five: 3
```

Particularly handy for analyzing log files to see how many SQL queries are being run after certain points in code...