# Printing n number of lines between string matches in a separate field

Tags: string, awk, sed, grep

I have two files, File_1 containing IDs and File_2 containing the data I want to match. Each file looks as follow:

```
File_1
Cluster 43
Cluster 51
Cluster 145
Cluster 160

File_2
>Cluster 43
0       5249nt, >CL276.Contig2_All... at +/98.55%
1       6413nt, >CL276.Contig3_All... *
2       5375nt, >CL276.Contig5_All... at +/95.91%
3       5405nt, >CL276.Contig6_All... at +/98.33%
>Cluster 51
0       6298nt, >CL5173.Contig2_All... *
1       3421nt, >CL5173.Contig3_All... at +/99.50%
2       1017nt, >CL5173.Contig4_All... at +/98.13%
3       503nt, >Unigene10077_All... at +/98.01%
>Cluster 145
0       4772nt, >CL1798.Contig5_All... at +/98.49%
1       4782nt, >CL1798.Contig8_All... *
2       4781nt, >CL1798.Contig10_All... at +/99.27%
3       4773nt, >CL1798.Contig11_All... at +/99.25%
>Cluster 160
0       2883nt, >CL4790.Contig2_All... at +/95.87%
1       4699nt, >CL4790.Contig3_All... *
2       1274nt, >CL4790.Contig7_All... at +/99.37%
3       4616nt, >CL4790.Contig14_All... at -/95.65%
```

I need to find in File_2 all lines that match the IDs in File_1 and print the matching line eg "Cluster 43", and in a separate filed print all lines between matching strings. The desired output should look like this

```
Cluster 43 5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
           6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
           5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
           5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51 6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
           3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
           1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
           503nt Unigene10077_All
```

Using my commmand line (see below) I can process the files to obtain the matching lines in File_2 based on IDs from File_1, print the matching lines and the all lines between the matches and also remove every unwanted information from each line, 
however I am having problems finding a solution to print the lines between matches in a separate field as in the desired output shown above.

my command line

```
$ grep -A4 -Fwf File_1 File_2 | sed 's/All.*//g;/Contig/s/.$/_All/g;/Unigene/s/.$/_All/g;s/-.*//;/^$/d;s/.//;s/[,>]//g' | awk '{print $1, $2}' > my_wanted_file
```

the resulting output

```
$head my_wanted_file

Cluster 43
5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51
6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
503nt Unigene10077_All
```

In an effort to fullfil my aim I wrote the following command lines:

```
$ awk '/^Cluster/ {if ('\n') {printf NR==4}}' my_wanted_file | head
```

but it prints nothing.

Then I tried with:

```
$ awk '/Cluster/ {for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {getline; print}}' my_wanted_file | head
```

but it only prints contiguously the lines between each match (Cluster) as below

```
5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
503nt Unigene10077_All
4772nt CL1798.Contig5_All
4782nt CL1798.Contig8_All
```

I can't find the way to go from this

```
Cluster 43
5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51
6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
503nt Unigene10077_All
```

to this

```
Cluster 43 5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
           6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
           5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
           5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51 6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
           3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
           1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
           503nt Unigene10077_All
```

I would appreciate very much a bit of help in this regard.

Comment: I couldn't see `Cluster 43` in file2, could you please correct your samples more accurately so that we can better understand it. BTW thank you for putting your efforts inside your question, keep it up and let us know after editing your post please.

Comment: It is because File_2 is a large file, I just showed the first few lines, the strings in File_1 come further down in File_2.

Comment: yes that's perfectly fine to show only few lines of sample. My request is to post common lines etc so that we could make it out how to match both files and get desired output, so input and output shown should be in sync.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have changed the lines shown for File_2. Now the info match in both files. Thank you for your request

Comment: You really should take another look at [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181686/1745001), it'd make what you're doing now much easier too since it simply treats each Cluster block as a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Though I am not sure you need values till `All` or before string `at` or is `All` really coming in your Input_file so we could change regex accordingly too.

This will take care of equal spaces too for all the lines.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  $0=">"$0
  a[$0]
  max=max>length($0)?max:length($0)
  next
}
FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{
  spaces=sprintf("%-"max+1"s",OFS)
}
/^>/{
  found=val=count=""
}
/^>/ && $0 in a{
  found=1
  val= $0
  remain_spaces=sprintf("%-"max-length($0)+1"s",OFS)
  next
}
found{
  gsub(/^>|at.*/,"",$3)
  sub(/,/,"",$2)
  printf("%s\n",++count==1?val remain_spaces $2 OFS $3:spaces $2 OFS $3)
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
>Cluster 43  5249nt CL276.Contig2_All...
             6413nt CL276.Contig3_All...
             5375nt CL276.Contig5_All...
             5405nt CL276.Contig6_All...
>Cluster 51  6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All...
             3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All...
             1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All...
             503nt Unigene10077_All...
>Cluster 145 4772nt CL1798.Contig5_All...
             4782nt CL1798.Contig8_All...
             4781nt CL1798.Contig10_All...
             4773nt CL1798.Contig11_All...
>Cluster 160 2883nt CL4790.Contig2_All...
             4699nt CL4790.Contig3_All...
             1274nt CL4790.Contig7_All...
             4616nt CL4790.Contig14_All...
```

Comment: Dear @RavinderSingh13 The output looks like below:                                   Cluster 43      5249nt CL276.Contig2_All...
                        6413nt CL276.Contig3_All...
                        5375nt CL276.Contig5_All...
                        5405nt CL276.Contig6_All...
Cluster 43      44
                        6380nt CL1653.Contig4_All...
                        1074nt Unigene864_All...
                        1069nt Unigene42819_All...
Cluster 43      45
                        6380nt CL4699.Contig1_All...

Comment: @LeonardoMartin, Sorry but without code tags not understanding it. Check my EDIT now, I fixed spaces part if that is what your question is, lemme know?

Comment: Dear @RavinderSingh13 it works perfectly now. Yes I Need values untill _All exactly as your sample Output. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @LeonardoMartin, Your welcome, glad that it helped you, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for multi-char RS, ENDFILE and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`)?

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    tgts[$0]
    next
}
ENDFILE {
    RS = "(^|\n)(>|$)"
    FS = "\n"
}
(FNR > 1) && ($1 in tgts) {
    gsub(/\n[0-9]+\s+/,"\n")
    gsub(/[,>]|[.]{3}[^\n]*/,"")
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $1, $i
        gsub(/./," ",$1)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk File_1 File_2
Cluster 43 5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
           6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
           5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
           5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51 6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
           3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
           1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
           503nt Unigene10077_All
Cluster 145 4772nt CL1798.Contig5_All
            4782nt CL1798.Contig8_All
            4781nt CL1798.Contig10_All
            4773nt CL1798.Contig11_All
Cluster 160 2883nt CL4790.Contig2_All
            4699nt CL4790.Contig3_All
            1274nt CL4790.Contig7_All
            4616nt CL4790.Contig14_All
```

Comment: Dear Ed Morton, your solution also works very well. Thanks to you and @RavinderSingh13 for taking the time. I am Voting your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is:

```
Cluster 43
5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51
6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
503nt Unigene10077_All
```

Assuming there will be exactly 5 lines for each cluster, you can run it through:

```
sed 'N;s/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/|/; n;s/^/|/; n;s/^/|/; n;s/^/|/'
```

Or maybe like this, which looks shorter, no idea if better:

```
sed 's/^/|/' | sed 's/^|//;N;s/\n//;N;N;N'
```

To get:

```
Cluster 43|5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
|6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
|5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
|5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51|6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
|3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
|1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
|503nt Unigene10077_All
```

You may choose other separator then `|`. Now you can run it via `column` to columnize it:

```
column -t -s '|' -o ' '
```

Which will output:

```
Cluster 43 5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
           6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
           5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
           5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51 6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
           3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
           1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
           503nt Unigene10077_All
```

The whole command I tested it with looks like this:

```
cat <<EOF |
Cluster 43
5249nt CL276.Contig2_All
6413nt CL276.Contig3_All
5375nt CL276.Contig5_All
5405nt CL276.Contig6_All
Cluster 51
6298nt CL5173.Contig2_All
3421nt CL5173.Contig3_All
1017nt CL5173.Contig4_All
503nt Unigene10077_All
EOF
sed 'N;s/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/|/; n;s/^/|/; n;s/^/|/; n;s/^/|/' | column -t -s '|' -o ' '
```

Comment: Dear KamilCuk, it didn't work as expected. I got the following warnings           column: invalid option -- 'o'                                                                                        but thank you anyway for taking the time

Comment: I guess you are on bsd. Either install gnu column, or you could just remove the `-o ' '`.